# Dialogflow always triggering default intent

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, dialogflow-es

I have made android app which connects with dialog flow. dialog flow have 2  intents but only default intent is triggered each time irrespective of what i type? please help.

[image]

Comment: I've never seen that green circle with the arrow and yellow exclamation point. Does it say anything when you over over it?

Comment: Prisoner that's Grammarly, any help with the question